# Bivariate Kernel Density Estimator in Java

Tags: java, math

I'm writing some software in which I need to compute bivariate densities of an x-y grid. Are there any libraries that might help me in Java for this? I've seen a lot of stuff in R, but nothing in Java.

Comment: You might want to ask in http://metaoptimize.com/qa (it's down right now though).  It's a AI/machine learning SO clone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be what you want: http://code.google.com/p/beast-mcmc/source/browse/trunk/src/dr/geo/KernelDensityEstimator2D.java

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking for something just like this.